# Windows 10 Home PC cannot access shared folder on Windows 7 Home Premium Laptop

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have a PC whose name is `A-PC`, operating system is `Windows 10 Home` 64-bit and workgroup is `WORKGROUP`. It is connected to my Router wired. To login I use  `ChumbA` username and `PasswordA` password; `ChumbA` is a Local Account Administrator on `A-PC`.

I have a Laptop whose name is `B-LAPTOP`, operating system is `Windows 7 Home Premium` 64-bit and workgroup is `WORKGROUP`. It is connected to same Router wireless. To login I use  `ChumbB` username and `PasswordB` password; `ChumbB` is a Local Account Administrator on `B-LAPTOP`.

From `A-PC` I can ping `B-LAPTOP` and from `B-LAPTOP` I can ping `A-PC`.

On `A-PC` I shared a folder to Everyone with Read/Write access. Its path is `\\A-PC\Share`.

From `B-LAPTOP` when I try to access this shared folder `\\A-PC\Share`, I was asked for username and password; I supplied `A-PC\ChumbA` as username and `PasswordA` password. And I was able to access the shared folder.

**Now here is the problem:**

On `B-LAPTOP` I shared a folder to Everyone with Read/Write access. Its path is `\\B-LAPTOP\Share`.

From `A-PC` when I try to access this shared folder `\\B-LAPTOP\Share`, I get this error message:

> Windows cannot access \\B-LAPTOP\Share
>
> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem
>   with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems,
>   click Diagnose.
>
> Error code: 0x80004005
>
> Unspecified error

I tried Diagnose but it could not find the problem.

What could be the reason?

Comment: When sharing files and folders within a `Workgroup`, I always recommend that people create an identical set of login/password combinations on each machine. It makes everything so much easier! Try creating the `ChumbA` login on the laptop with the same password it has on the Windows 10 Home machine and see if you can access the laptop share over the network.

Comment: @Run5k Thanks your solution worked. But I still dont understand why the laptop was able to access the PC share before?

Comment: Always glad to help.  When you are dealing with a mixed OS environment, strange things can happen.  For many years, it has been a *"best practice"* for those of us who configure a Windows `Workgroup` on our home network to ensure that each machine has the exact same login/password combinations to help make file sharing relatively smooth and easy.  With the advent of Windows operating systems that utilize a Microsoft account for login purposes, it is even easier than before.

Comment: Thanks. If you can make your comment an answer then I can accept it and be done with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sharing files and folders within a `Workgroup`, I always recommend that people create an identical set of login/password combinations on each machine. It makes everything so much easier, and for many years it has been a "best practice" for those of us who configure a Windows `Workgroup` on our home network.  With the advent of Windows operating systems that utilize a Microsoft account for login purposes, it is even easier than before.

Try creating the `ChumbA` login on the laptop with the same password it has on the Windows 10 Home machine and see if you can access the laptop share over the network.